# How to expand child from JSON, load data after click parent - D3.Js - force directed layout

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I want to use this example
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093130

Link is `Collapsible Force Layout` and load all nodes from JSON in first loading.

**Question:**

I want to load child after click parent's node and expand after click.

When collapse each node, destroy all nodes are as child.

**How to implement idea?**

Note: my graph is huge and web browser doesn't respond to load. Now I want to load/destroy data gradually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it like this:

On click of the node fetch the children associated with the node:

```
function getMyData(d) {
  //return the url for the parent node.
  if (d.name == 'graph') {
    return "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cyrilcherian/231657f6c86d540adf64/raw/375f89aaa65d16bbbda904c7f17a132face1a7d6/graph_children.json";
  } else if (d.name == 'cluster') {
    return "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cyrilcherian/dbf9f0b2180201e4cdbe/raw/a7e6361349fe06b6c16f7f376d07dae36da89848/cluster_children.json";
  }  else if (d.name == 'analytics') {
    return "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cyrilcherian/0efc76bd75386bf89961/raw/5d32ea77f1d34e8ca40f749ce9d501669e8563a4/analytic_children.json";
  } else if (d.name == 'flare') {
    return "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cyrilcherian/b9bcb0fdc398bd691641/raw/11a79edf99511cf040ffcb98ae9c30895798ae5e/flare.json";
  } else
    return [];
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {

  if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return; // ignore drag
  if (d.children) {
    d.children = null;
    update();
  } else {
    //do your ajax call to get the chldren

    var url = getMyData(d);
    d3.json(url, function(error, json) {
      d.children = json;
      update();//update on ajax success.
    })

  }

}
```

Here these are my ajax calls to load its children based on the parent node `"https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cyrilcherian/b9bcb0fdc398bd691641/raw/11a79edf99511cf040ffcb98ae9c30895798ae5e/flare.json"`

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/JOau5Tyknqx2zdCZN81D?p=preview)

You need to click the flare/cluster/graph/analytics node to load its children via ajax.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks. but how to destroy when collapse node and free memory?
is there a new way for create `getMyData()` function? I have a lot of node.

Comment: see when you doing `d.children = null;` in the click event you are destroying the children node. In the update method you have `node.exit().remove();` which will destroy all no needed nodes and `link.exit().remove();` will remove all not needed links after the click